# Xcode - "no such file or directory" for headers

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, zxing

I'm hoping that somebody with some experience of iOS development can help with this issue.

I'm working with PhoneGap and ZXing. I've followed the enclosed readme, as well as these instructions: http://yannickloriot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-zxing-in-xcode-4/

PhoneGap plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/BarcodeScanner

It seems many others have experienced this problem. When I compile, I get these errors:

```
 ZXingWidgetController.h: No such file or directory
 QRCodeReader.h: No such file or directory
```

In my project -> Build Settings -> Header Search Paths, I have defined:

```
 $(SRCROOT)/zxing/cpp/core/src/
 $(SRCROOT)/zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes (recursive)
```

I have checked the locations of those folders, and they match what is defined in the header search paths. In the plugins folder, the file "`BarcodeScanner.h`" has these lines, where the errors are being produced:

```
#import "ZXingWidgetController.h"
#import "QRCodeReader.h"
```

Any ideas? I've scoured the Internet and tried just about everything. I'm just about to go insane.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's an old project.

I'd create a new project.  The header search paths shouldn't be needed.

Then add all the files in the original project to the new one.  (Of course, there may be a few subtleties that being familiar with iOS would make easier.)

Comment: I've tried creating new projects, but am not having much luck. I've tried both with and without the header search paths... :(

Comment: you've visually confirmed the files are present and listed in the project?

Comment: Yeah, they're definitely in the location specified. I've copied the path from Finder and re-typed it several times over to ensure there are no typos to be found. I expect I'm probably just referencing them incorrectly or something, as I'm brand new to Xcode.